Pocket Tens vs Set
Here's a hand I played today in a tournament and I lost. Did I play right?
Pre-flop, I'm bottom with pocket Tens, blinds 1.6K/800,  4 limps and I bet 5K. Two folds and another two guys (SB and CO) follow me.
Flop: K 6 4 rainbow
check, check and I bet 10K, and the two players follow me.
Turn: 4
check, check and I bet 15K, CO folds, and SB calls.
River: 5
SB goes all in. After thinking a bit I went all in too (both with similar stacks, about 30BB left) I thought it was really difficult that he had KX or 4X so I called.
SB showed pocket sixes :(

I think your biggest misstep here is your betting amount, your understanding of how strong pocket pairs are/the values they have and not considering your opponents actions and how they influence our decisions.
So let's start with when action gets to you, we have 4 limpers, the SB and BB already in the pot, meaning the pot is currently at 8.8k, and you bet 5k. This is really not enough to thin the field at all. If I have put in 1.6k, by the time it reaches me to call the 5k bet you've made I only need to put in 3.4k (4.2k for the SB) more to win 13.8k. You can call a lot of things here profitably, plus you need to consider that if someone is limping early positions, they've already made a mistake so they'll call wider than they should. Once one person calls, then it means more people can call even wider too.
So my question here to you here is what are you hoping to achieve with betting your tens? To me it looks like you're automatically going pocket pair, good hand auto bet, but I don't see any more thought from your post into why you picked 5k. If you're intent is to narrow the field, which it should be with a pocket pair you have failed to bet enough to do what you want to do. Ask yourself when betting what you're trying to achieve with it and will it likely work, try to not go to automatic behaviours.
Pocket pairs always play best in position (to be fair you have this) and heads-up. When we're multiway medium and lower pocket pairs are weak, you're hoping for a set most of the time and it's not going to happen often enough to be the right thing to do.
So then the flop comes, 1 over is likely to happen over 3 cards with TTs. Your bet here again is an auto bet and too small, to achieve anything really. I'm not even sure what you're trying to achieve here, are you trying to win the pot now, are you value betting? You're betting 10k into a pot of 21.4k. Your bet size is fine headsup, but I prefer bigger or smaller than 50%. Multiway pot it's harder to value bet here, and it's not going to make your opponents fold. SB range can be wide, the COs range can be wide here too, they could absolutely have things like K8+, given they're limping pre as well I wouldn't even be surprised for suited connectors, people love these, some goofy two pair, sets. So again what is your bet of 10k trying to achieve, if it's value increase your bet, if someone is going to call pre, they're probably going to call a larger bet on the flop anyway so you'll increase your return here, I'm thinking 70%+ might be better, and if you're trying to make them fold it's not enough.
Ok so now the turn, pot is now 51.4k, and again you bet 15k. Again my question and point will be the same what is this bet achieving, it's even a lesser percentage than before, we're losing to even more hands, things like A4 are now ahead. This to me is an auto bet, you're not thinking of the opponents ranges, what your bet is hoping to do. I think if you ask yourself what does 15k into 51.4k actually do, you'll find if someone is calling preflop, on a flop, that 15k is not going to do anything to deter them from calling a turn. You haven't mentioned opponents stack depths either. If someone has the straight draw as well they have an even better price to call now. This to me looks like a lower buy-in game, and these type of players LOVE chasing. At this point it's gone limp from both other players, you've bet, they've called, they've done this 3 times now. I'd be having major alarm bells in my head here. I think once you're on the turn you have two choices play for it all, or I'd prefer a pot control approach, just check.
River now comes a 5, so a lot of hands have got there, we're losing to a lot of our opponents range, we effectively only have a bluff catcher, and not even a great bluff catcher at that. A lot of lower stake players aren't thinking about poker that deep, they're playing for fun and more casual, it's extremely rare that these type of players are going to bluff jam a river. Especially with the action. They have just let you build a pot for them, an aggressive player on the button sure might jam a river after betting every street, but out of position it's less likely.
I think once you get to the river you should be asking yourself what are you beating, and what would your opponent play this way, i.e. get to the river and then donk jam into you with. You're losing to any King, you're losing to any pocket pair over a ten, you're losing to any 4 Combo, you're losing to many lower suited connectors, you're losing to 4s, 5s and 6s. You're beating maybe 9s if someone is playing without thinking at all, or a pure bluff. The player shoving into you if they wanted to bluff had better opportunities to do so during the hand before this point. You mentioned that you found it hard to believe they had specific hands, but I don't think you have refined their range or thought about that as the hand has progressed.
So I think a lot of mistakes in this hand. To sum up and offer advise in a TL;DR format:

Multiple limpers pre-flop, in position, betting small is a mistake. Medium pocket pairs, and any pocket pair play good heads-up. Your bet of 5k is wrong and too small. Always ask yourself before betting what is the intent and hope of this bet, if it was to get headsup I think you'd realise you need to go bigger.
Looks like you're making auto decisions - Don't do this, think about the hand, and the hands you've played with people. Poker is a game of incomplete information and making informed decisions, it is not a single hand game. Players tendencies matter, think before you act always.
Flop, again like the first point here, the bet is too small. Ask yourself what you're trying to achieve with it. You should be getting headsup with pocket pairs to put yourself in the strongest position. Bet bigger to reduce the field, although in this case I think a check for pot control is probably better.
Turn, again like point 1 and 3 your bet is an auto decision, and I can't see your intent of it. In this case you've fired pre and on the flop, your bet here is not good. Check for pot control I think is better. Makes calling a smaller river bet easier.
You haven't considered how an opponents range and tendencies matter and should be updated as the hand progresses. You mentioned how you can't see how they beat you here, and I'd counter and say with the limited information you've given I can't see how you could be ahead here. Just fold. Chips saved are incredibly valuable, sometimes the most important thing you can do in a tournament is make that disciplined fold, even if it hurts, to live to fight another day.

